# Qt QQuickView visual bug / flickering on resize

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying integrate some QML/Qt Quick 2 elements into a Qt 5.4 c++ application. So far I've been able to display my QML elements exactly as I want inside the Qt window, but I'm experiencing some flickering and similar visual bugs at random times and especially when the window is being resized or when a QML element changes color. I had no such problems when my QML code was running by itself. Are there any obvious solutions to this problem?

The exact nature of the bug is that the "topbar" element is displayed stacked on top of the "menubar" element for a fraction of a second. This happens more often if the window is resized or if say an element in the QML view changes color.

main.cpp:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();
return a.exec();
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
QStackedWidget * mainStackWidget = new QStackedWidget();

//Init of QML TopBar widget
QQuickView *topBarView= new QQuickView();
topBarView->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
topBarView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/TopBar.qml"));
QWidget *topBarWidget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(topBarView);
topBarWidget->setMinimumSize(1024, 150);

//Init of QML menu widget
QQuickView *menuView = new QQuickView();
menuView->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
menuView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/SideBar.qml"));
QWidget *menuWidget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(menuView);
menuWidget->setMinimumSize(1024, 500);

//Setting the layout
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(topBarWidget);
mainStackWidget->addWidget(menuWidget);
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(mainStackWidget);
centralWidget()->setLayout(ui->verticalLayout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking apart my own program it was clear that a "Progressbar" element in the topbar QML element was causing the visual bugs. Setting more of the Progressbar's settings such as in the example below solved almost all the glitching visuals, although I don't really know why.

```
ProgressBar {
    value: slider.value
    style: ProgressBarStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            radius: 2
            color: "lightgray"
            border.color: "gray"
            border.width: 1
            implicitWidth: 200
            implicitHeight: 24
        }
        progress: Rectangle {
            color: "lightsteelblue"
            border.color: "steelblue"
        }
    }
}
```